# Discrete logarithm problem in subgroup of index 2. ElGamal

Tags: discrete-logarithm, elgamal-encryption, group-theory

I need some insight for the following problem in ElGamal encryption procedure. It is stated that ElGamal problem in a group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ becomes easier in subgroups. Assume I have a subgroup of index 2. Can you explain how is easier the discrete logarithm problem in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, algorithms, such as *baby step giant step*  with time and memory complexity $$T=M=O(\sqrt{N})$$ or *Pollard's rho*  with time and memory complexity $$T=O(\sqrt{N}),\quad M=O(1)$$have complexities that depend on the size $N$ of the group over which the DL is defined.

So $N=\mathbb{Z}_p^{\ast}=p-1,$ while a subgroup of index 2 has size $N'=(p-1)/2$ and the complexity improves accordingly.

Comment: Complexity is only improving by a constant, is that so bad?

Comment: The subgroup used in El Gamal can have a much higher index, i.e., be much smaller.